# Jess: Obtaining fact-id of already asserted fact?

Tags: java, jess

So when you assert an already asserted fact in Jess, rather than assert returning the id of that fact, it returns FALSE. It seems in Java you can use "findFactByFact", which I assume is the way, but how do I use this if I don't have the fact? When I try to pass a template instance to a java function, all that is passed is the name of the template in string format...

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's obvious: if you don't have a value that is required for calling a method you can't call that method.

Answer (score 1):

So I got around the problem by passing all the content of the facts to a Java method, constructing a duplicate fact, and using this duplicate fact to look up the original fact. But it's cumbersome as I will possibly need multiple methods to accomplish this for different types of facts. What I was hoping for was that there is a way to simply assert a fact in Jess, and get the existing fact-id if it already exists, rather than FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some cogent reason for obtaining a fact id? (I doubt it - at least, I've never felt the need.)

However. The simple function below either returns the fact id of the previously asserted fact matching the fact-as-string argument, or nil.

```
(deffunction find-id (?aFact)
   (eval (str-cat "(defquery search ?f<-" ?aFact ")"))
   (bind ?result (run-query* search))
   (if (?result next) then
      (return (call (?result get f) getFactId))
   else
      (return nil)))
```

Given a fact definition

```
(deftemplate paper  (slot author  ) (slot number))
(deftemplate review (slot reviewer) (slot paper))
(deffacts MAIN::myfacts
   (paper (author Joe)(number 1))
   (review (reviewer "1") (paper 1))
   (review (reviewer "2") (paper 1))
   (review (reviewer "3") (paper 1))
   (paper (author Jack)(number 2))
   (review (reviewer "1") (paper 2))
   (review (reviewer "2") (paper 2))
)
```

we can execute

```
(reset)
(printout t "id=" (find-id "(paper (author Joe)(number 1))") crlf)
(printout t "id=" (find-id "(review (reviewer \"2\")(paper 2))") crlf)
(printout t "id=" (find-id "(paper (author Fred)(number 3))") crlf)
```

to obtain

```
id=1
id=7
id=nil
```

Comment: I'm using Jess to build symbolic tree-expressions for doing logical inferences, where the facts are the link to other nodes in the tree. Still not sure if it's the best way but I haven't seen any good examples yet. But it's working so far at least.